# How to determine when this two variable transformation is invertible?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, systems-of-equations, transformation

I am given:

$$ X= U \cos(V) \tag{1}\\ $$
$$ Y = U \sin V \tag{2}$$

Now, I need to:

> a) Give the respective ranges for $U$ and $V$ in order that the transformation defined is one to one.
>   and
>
> b) With the given range found in (a),  find $U$ and $V$ in terms of $X$ and $Y$.

I don't know how to answer (a). I've tried sketching $X$ and $Y$ and can see that there are certain ranges for they will not be invertible since $\cos(V)$ and $\sin(V)$ are periodic. But I don't know how to translate this into specific ranges for $U$ and $V$.

If I start with $X$, then I can see that $0 \le V \le \pi$ and $U>0$ works because $X$ will be able to take on values from $-U$ to $U$ as defined in $(1)$ but then that will not work for $(2)$ ie $Y$ will not be invertible in that range. So, what is the solution and how should I approach this question?

For (b), I tried to solve by following the usual way of solving simultaneous equations and got the following:

$$\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{X}{U}\right)=V$$
$$\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{Y}{U}\right)=V $$

and it does not look like this will lead to an answer. What should I do to proceed? I suspect a trig identity may be involved.

EDIT:

The full question is:
[image]

Comment: For (b) you can just divide equations by one another.

Comment: Eugene is right, but note that doing this throws some information away, and the result of that division suggests a domain on which the transformation is invertible that is smaller than is necessary to achieve invertibility. Whether this matters depends on the situation, I suppose. (To be clear, the question itself is slightly misleadingly worded: There are *many* such domains on which the transformation is invertible.)

Comment: @Travis I've posted to full question. Does that help to narrow down the domains?

Comment: @mauna Ah, yes: Since $X$ and $Y$ are random variable, we want to choose not just a domain on which the transformation is invertible onto its image, but a domain $\Omega$ in $UV$-space so that, via the transformation, hits every point in the $XY$-plane $\Bbb R^2$ once, that is, is an invertible map $\Omega \to \Bbb R^2$.  Note that thie coordinate transformation just defines the usual polar coordinates on the plane.

Comment: I don't really understand your explanation. Could you please illustrate the points you want to make with a solution too?

Comment: You can use $ (U,V) \in (0,\infty) \times (0,2 \pi) $. Every point $ (x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^{2} \setminus \{ (0,0) \} $ can be written as
$$
(r \cos(\theta),r \sin(\theta))
$$
for a unique $ r > 0 $ and a unique $ \theta \in [0,2 \pi) $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that if $X \neq 0$, we can divide the equations to obtain 
$$
\frac{Y}{X} = \frac{\sin V}{\cos V} = \tan V
$$
If we square both equations and add them, we obtain
$$
X^2 + Y^2 = U^2 \sin^2 V + U^2 \cos^2 V = U^2
$$
Solving these two equations for $U$ and $V$ looks straight-forward, but we must be careful when inverting the $\tan$ function using $\arctan$.
Since the range of $\arctan$ is $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, we will need to restrict $V$ to lie in this interval.
Also notice that when $X < 0$, $\cos(\arctan(\frac{Y}{X})) = -X$ and $\sin(\arctan(\frac{Y}{X})) = -Y$. 
We will therefore need to incorporate a switch of signs when $X$ is negative.

When $X = 0$, it is easy to see that setting $U = |Y|$ and $V = \frac{\pi}{2}$ if $Y \geq 0$ and $V = -\frac{\pi}{2}$ if $Y < 0$ will yield the correct values of $X$ and $Y$.
Putting all this together, we can invert the transformation when $(U,V)$ lies in the set $(-\infty,\infty) \times [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$
using the following formulas:
\begin{align}
U &= \begin{cases}
\sqrt{X^2+Y^2} & \text{if $X \geq 0$}\\
-\sqrt{X^2+Y^2} & \text{if $X < 0$}
\end{cases}\\
V &= \begin{cases}
\arctan\left(\frac{Y}{X}\right) &\text{if $X \neq 0$} \\
\frac{\pi}{2} & \text{if $X = 0$ and $Y \geq 0$}\\
-\frac{\pi}{2} & \text{if $X = 0$ and $Y < 0$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

To compute the joint density, all we need is the determinant  of the Jacobian of the original transformation:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial X}{\partial U} & \frac{\partial X}{\partial V}\\
\frac{\partial Y}{\partial U} & \frac{\partial Y}{\partial V}
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
\cos V & -U \sin V\\
\sin V & U \cos V
\end{vmatrix}
=U \cos^2 V + U \sin^2 V = U
$$
Using the change-of-variables formula, we can compute the joint density of $(U,V)$ as
\begin{align}
f(u,v) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{u^2 \cos^2 v + u^2 \cos^2 v}{2}\right)\cdot |u| \cdot \mathbb{1}\left\{-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq v \leq \frac{\pi}{2}\right\}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \cdot |u| \cdot \exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\mathbb{1}\left\{-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq v \leq \frac{\pi}{2}\right\}
\end{align}
where $\mathbb{1}\left\{\cdot\right\}$ is an indicator function equal to 1 if the expression in the braces is true and zero otherwise.
Notice that this implies $U$ and $V$ are independently distributed, with $|U| \sim \text{Weibull}(1,2)$ and $V \sim \text{Uniform}(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Comment: @mauna Does this  sufficiently answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand your solution except that I am not sure how to use it to calculate the joint probability density $f_{U,V}(u,v)$ of $U$ and $V$. In particular, will the Jacobian simply be the partial derivatives of $X$ and $Y$ with respect to $U$ and $V$? Also, the inverse transformation does not seem to matter because the product of the pdf of the standard normal variables $X$ and $Y$ will have an $X^2+Y^2$ term and this is simply equal to $U^2$, as you have shown. So, there is only one $f_{U,V}(u,v)$ for all possible values of $(U,V)$, right?

Comment: Also, will your inverse transformation be different if you had let $(U,V) \in (0,\infty) \times (0,2 \pi)$ as per Berrick Caleb Fillmore's comment?

Comment: @mauna I've edited the response to include the joint probability distribution. Let me know if that answers your first question.

Comment: As far as your second question, you could no longer invert $\frac{Y}{X}=\tan V$ immediately using $\arctan$. It would still be possible to construct an inverse transformation, but I think the final formula would be slightly more complicated.